# How to fetch GROUP BY data from ndb query

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

As per the docs I am using like this:

```
QueryHistory.query(projection=[QueryHistory.SFDCUser_id],group_by=[QueryHistory.SFDCUser_id])
```

but it is not giving any results.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues I can see:

1. You must run `fetch()` or `get()` on the `Query` object produced by the snipit you shared.
2. [you must ensure that `SFDCUser_id` is indexed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/projectionqueries#Python_Limitations_on_projections).

Comment: No, the Id is not indexed

Comment: I created the index then I used to group by like this.
list_of_keys = QueryHistory.query(projection=[QueryHistory.SFDCUser_id],group_by=[QueryHistory.SFDCUser_id]).fetch()

It gives me only only two results in list but i have more in datastore